# Uncaught Error: Module name "antlr4/index" has not been loaded yet for context on require.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs, antlr4

I try to use antlr4 on javascript, then read https://tomassetti.me/antlr-and-the-web/ and make but error has occurred.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/require.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var antlr4 = require('antlr4/index');
        var QueryLexer = require('gram/queryLexer');
        var QueryParser = require('gram/queryParser');
        document.getElementById("parse").addEventListener("click", function() {
            var input = document.getElementById("code").value;
            var chars = new antlr4.InputStream(input);
            var lexer = new QueryLexer.queryLexer(chars);
            var tokens = new antlr4.CommonTokenStream(lexer);
            var parser = new QueryParser.queryParser(tokens);
            parser.buildParseTrees = true;
            var tree = parser.query();
            console.log("Parsed: "+ tree);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="inputs">
<textarea id="code">
* play with antlr4
* write a tutorial
</textarea>
    <br/>
    <button id="parse">Parse</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The error may cause on "var antlr4 = require('antlr4/index');".
I downloaded antlr4 from http://www.antlr.org/download/index.html and put same tier of "index.html". In lib directory there exist "require.js".

**index.js**

```
exports.atn = require('./atn/index');
exports.codepointat = require('./polyfills/codepointat');
exports.dfa = require('./dfa/index');
exports.fromcodepoint = require('./polyfills/fromcodepoint');
exports.tree = require('./tree/index');
exports.error = require('./error/index');
exports.Token = require('./Token').Token;
exports.CharStreams = require('./CharStreams').CharStreams;
exports.CommonToken = require('./Token').CommonToken;
exports.InputStream = require('./InputStream').InputStream;
exports.FileStream = require('./FileStream').FileStream;
exports.CommonTokenStream = require('./CommonTokenStream').CommonTokenStream;
exports.Lexer = require('./Lexer').Lexer;
exports.Parser = require('./Parser').Parser;
var pc = require('./PredictionContext');
exports.PredictionContextCache = pc.PredictionContextCache;
exports.ParserRuleContext = require('./ParserRuleContext').ParserRuleContext;
exports.Interval = require('./IntervalSet').Interval;
exports.Utils = require('./Utils');
```

I think there are no problems, because require path('antlr4/index') is not wrong.
But error has occurred. Please give me some idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you show in your question **cannot** work as-is with RequireJS. You'd have to write the `require` calls differently, or wrap all the `require` calls you have in a `define` so as to use the [CommonJS support](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#cjsmodule) that RequireJS provides.

But **the tutorial is not asking you to use RequireJS**. if you go to the [github repo](https://github.com/ftomassetti/antlr-web-example) that the writer of the tutorial provided, you'll see:

> Require.js was obtained from https://github.com/letorbi/smoothie/blob/master/standalone/require.js

You have to use that file, which is not RequireJS, but something similar to it in the sense that it also loads scripts, and yet different from RequireJS in the sense that it seems to support the CommonJS module format as-is, which RequireJS doesn't.

Comment: Thanks:) I rewrite require.js like https://github.com/letorbi/smoothie/blob/master/standalone/require.js , then it did well.